# Series -- Coefficient Cn and Radius of Convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, factorial

[image: Valid XHTML].

I'm lost, and my textbook is failing me

Comment: Your textbook was written by a PhD (hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

To identify the $c_n$, look up the definition of MacLaurin series. This will tell you how $c_n$ relates to $f^{(n)}(0)$.

To figure out the radius of convergence, fix $x$ and use the ratio test. This will give you $|x|<R$. (You have to figure out $R$.) After you do this, substitute $x = R$ and $x=-R$ into the series to determine whether or not the MacLaurin series converges at the endpoints of the interval of convergence.

Comment: Thanks. I got 7 for radius of convergence and (-1)^n*n!/(7^n*(n+1))/n! for cn.